# Help solving this problem

Tags: probability

A population consists of 25 men and 25 women. A simple random sample (draws at random without replacement) of 4 people is chosen. Find the chance that in the sample there are more women than men.

Comment: No motivation, no sign of any effort, no indication of source, no reason for interest, no explanation of what OP knows about the problem. This is the kind of question that tends to get closed very quickly here. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{50}{4}$ ways to choose our $4$ people, all **equally likely**.

There are $\binom{25}{4}\binom{24}{0}$ ways to choose $4$ women and $0$ men, and $\binom{25}{3}\binom{25}{1}$ ways to choose $3$ women and $1$ man.

**Remark:** One can be a little more clever, and take advantage of symmetry. Calculate the probability of a $2$-$2$ split, using the same method as above. Call this probability $p$. Then the probability the split is not $2$-$2$ is $1-p$, and therefore the probability the women are in the majority is $\frac{1-p}{2}$.

This approach would save a lot of work if we were picking, say, $16$ people from $25$ men and $25$ women. With $4$, it may be simpler not to be clever.

Comment: Thank you for your help i just solve it. Solution: 0.3047

Comment: The answer I get is approximately $0.3046027$.